# Pandas Series values are not updated after applying a simple string function

Tags: python, pandas

Given a simple `dataframe`:

```
  lendf = pd.read_csv('/git/opencv-related/audio_and_text_files_lens.csv',
       names=['path','duration'])
```

I need to do a simple operation on the first column:

```
  lendf['path'] = lendf['path'].replace('.wav','.txt')
```

Let us check the result:

```
  print(lendf['path'][:10])
```

[image]

So then nothing happened - we still have `.wav` in there instead of `.txt`.   I am following a number of references including a simple one here:  [Pandas Apply function on Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036106/pandas-apply-function-on-column). That answer provides the same pattern:

> You can just do `df['B'] = df.B.notnull()`.

So why were the values not updated - and what is the correction to this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want `str.replace` not `replace`.
Use this code.

```
lendf['path'].str.replace('.wav', '.txt')
```

Comment: wow - that's what I needed.  Can you point me to where some basics of `pandas` live - describing this?

Comment: I just updated the title to say simple _string_ function. I had no idea there's a special sauce required for _string_ column values

Comment: Check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html.

Comment: Series.str.method is to apply string method such as replace, count, lower, upper to Series.

Comment: Yes that's a perfect location for this information.  You would not believe how many challenges to work with `pandas` between `indexing` and `loc`/`iloc` and then idiosyncracies

Comment: I have to wait another 5 mins ;)

Comment: @javadba once you get into it, you realise it's actually quite smart,it totally confused me at first too.

Comment: @Datanovice I have used `DataFrame` in spark and  `data.table` in `R` that are more powerful and less confusing. Ah well .